# Defining variables in function call vs passing locally defined variables to functions

Tags: java, android, performance

Is there any performance gain between following two scenarios ?

(Here, blueprint of function : `frameSwitchBlue(CardLayout layout, Drawable image, String str, boolean to_blue)` )

**1 -** Declaring local variables with parameter values and them passing them to function. Eg :

```
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tech_2);
String str = getResources().getString(R.string.tech_vibrt_play_snd);
CardLayout prev_view = findViewById(R.id.parent);
frameSwitchBlue(prev_view, image, str, false);
```

**2 -** Directly defining variables in function call. Eg :

```
frameSwitchBlue(findViewById(R.id.parent), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tech_2), getResources().getString(R.string.tech_vibrt_play_snd), false);
```

I am reducing object creating but a slight part of me says that the compiler will need to create those objects in the background anyway. Am I right ? Will scenario 2 give me any performance advantages (minus readability in scenario 1)?

Comment: I would say "no" with the same slight part in me talking - I however have no source to prove it. I just assume it could make a difference if you would track the according "assembler executions" since the variables remain "active" after the method call ... i personaly would however not try to optimize in this scenario and value the maintainability of my source higher than the few nanoseconds i may win on cpu execution level....

Comment: The performance gain, if anything, is too little to nothing to consider it over approach 1. However I can't back it up with a source either. IMO, readability matters more here. Also, it would help you better with debugging - the local variables would show up in the `Variables` view in eclipse.

Comment: @Shaishav: memory gains ???? where ??? The only difference is that the local variables are put on a local stack and then the references are used in the function call, as the local variables are not uesed later on, the code optimizer of the jit compiler will most likely endup with exactly the same results.

Comment: @GerritCap: OhK that makes sense as I just found out that jit exist in android since 2.2+